# Finding eigenvectors of parameterised matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Consider the matrix $A(p) \in \mathbb{R^{3x3}}$,
>
> $A(p) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 2\\  p+2 & 1 & -1\\ 
> -2 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$   which depends on the number $p \in \mathbb{R}$. For small $p$ the matrix $A(p)$ has an eigenvalue
> $\lambda (p)$ of algebraic multiplicty 1 such that $\lambda(0) = 1$
> and $\lambda(p)$ is differentiable at $p = 0$. Consider the
> eigenvector $\vec v(p)$ corresponding to $\lambda(p)$ for $A(p)$,
> scaled such that $$\vec v(p) = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\  v_2(p)\\  v_3(p)
>  \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> i.) Determine the eigenvector $\vec v(0)$ (this is the eigenvector for
> $p = 0$ for the eigenvalue 1, scaled such that its first component
> equals 1).
>
> ii.) Determine the derivatives $\lambda'(0),$ $v'_2(0)$, and $v'_3(0)$
> of $\lambda(p)$, $v'_2(0),$ and $v'_3(0)$ with respect to $p$ at $p = 0.$

So, for part i.), to calculate the eigenvector for $p = 0$, for eigenvalue $1$, we need to solve
$(A- I)\vec v = \vec 0$

Solving this I got

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1/2\\  0 & 1 & -3/2\\ 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2}p-2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

So $(-\frac{1}{2}p-2)(v_3) = 0,$ $v_2 = \frac{3}{2} v_3,$ $v_1 = \frac{1}{2}v_3,$ but I don't know where to go from here. From this, I get the impression that $v_1=v_2=v_3=0,$ but that can't be right, because we need to find $\vec v(p)$ such that $v_1 = 1$.

I've been overthinking this question too much, and it's starting to bug me. This feels like a question I should be able to answer, but I'm starting to dig myself a hole, and I think I'm starting to stray further and further from the solution. If someone could help me with this, I would be greatly appreciative.

(Apologies for this poorly formated question)

Comment: @user376343 Yeah, you're right. My bad

Comment: How did you get a matrix with $p$ in (i), if the task assumes that $p=0$?

Comment: @o.spectrum I just did Guassian elimination on $(A - \lambda I)$. Regardless, if we need to substitute $p=0$, can't we just do so, and, if I did guassian elimination correctly, we still have the same problem of $v1=v2=v3=0$?

Comment: Side note: I just realised I had a slight error in my write up of the question. In part i), I meant to write $\vec v(0)$, not $\vec v(p)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning the first part of your question: you are asked to find the eigenvector $\vec{v}(p)$, which corresponds to the eigenvalue $\lambda_1(0)=1$ of $A(0)$, as stated.

Honestly, I have no idea how did you get a matrix with $p$ in its, like the one you show in the post, having that $p$ is $0$, so let me just iterate through the steps that I took to calculate the desired eigenvector.

The eigenvector $\vec v(p=0)$, which corresponds to $\lambda_1(0)=1$ should take the following form:
$$
\vec{v}(0) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
v_2(0)
\\
v_3(0)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Let us then calculate $M(p, \lambda) = A-\lambda(p)I$ first:

$$
M(0, \lambda_1(0)) = A-\lambda_1(0)I = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 2 \\
0+2 & 1 & -1 \\
-2 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now, so that to find the desired eigenvector, corresponding to $\lambda_1(0)$, we have to solve $M(0, \lambda_1(0))\cdot\vec v = \vec 0$ or equivalently, apply Gauss elimination method for the following matrix: $\left[M(0, 1)\biggm| \vec 0\right]$ to obtain the solution:

$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
-1 & -1 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
-2 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right) \mathrel{\leadsto} \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
0 & -1 & 3/2 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right) \mathrel{\leadsto} \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
0 & 1 & 0 & 3v_3 /2 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & v_3/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
So, now we can say that the eigenvector is $\vec v(0) = v_3\cdot\begin{pmatrix} 1/2 \\ 3/2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$, where $v_3$ is any constant from $\mathbb{R}$. But, since the eigenvector is demanded to have its first entry being $1$, we need to have $v_3 = 2$, and so the desired eigenvector is $\vec v(0) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Since  you have mentioned that you got your matrix through Gauss elimination, then I’d assume that you could have made some small mistake in your calculations.

Comment: Man, this seems so straightforward now that you've explained it. You've really helped me out here. Thank you so much!! :) And yeah, you're absolutely right. I looked back through my work and made a careless mistake while doing Guassian elimination.

Comment: I’m glad to help :)